# Are "name that song" questions appropriate here?

Tags: discussion

Are "name that song" questions appropriate here on music.stackexchange.com?

For instance, if users have already asked on all the other forums, Reddit, etc.

Comment: The other issue with any 'name that tune' is that if you can't find it on Shazam/Soundhound, then the chances of recognition drop to less than marginal.

Comment: @Tetsujin Shazam/Soundhoud work for recorded music only AFAIK.  For "name that song" by melody, there's [Google Hum to Search](https://blog.google/products/search/hum-to-search/).  Still off topic for MP&T.

Comment: @Theodore -  Soundhound does humming too [or did last time I looked at it, which is quite a while ago now.]

Comment: You may find [What online resources are available for identifying songs from audio or score?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/10922/9288) helpful.

Comment: Note, there's the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room), where pretty much anything is fair game (within some bounds of human decency). No problem with "name this tune" there!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Sorry but "name that song" questions are *not* on-topic here on Music: Practice & Theory.

---

If you visit the Help center, in particular this page: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
... you'll see that a question is *not* on-topic if that question about:

> - identifying a song, style/genre, instrument/equipment, technique, chord progression, etc.

---

This type of question *used to be* on-topic for the [SE: Music fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions) site, but they aren't on-topic there anymore, (see their [help center page](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

---

If you have read through the help center of an SE site and then still aren't sure if a question is going to be on-topic, then you should ask on that site's meta page (i.e. [M: P&T Meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com)).